# lucid lynx runaway process

Tags: linux, boot, ubuntu-10.04, process

I am runnning lucid lynx with a gnome desktop. After uninstalling the klipper program there is a new and unwelcome process that begins at startup and takes around 66% of my cpu time. According to "top", the process number is 10 and the name of the process is "events/1". I am unable to kill the process using "top" or "kill". I have no extra startup applications except for gnome-do and tomboy. Eliminating these has no effect. Can anyone help?

Comment: The `events` processes are kernel threads. `top` doesn't indicate this apparently, but something like `ps ax` does, with square brackets.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I run ps ax I get the lines

 PPID=2,   PID=9  PGID=0   SID=0      TPGID=-1,  STAT=s,  
and I am told that events/1 is a subprocess of kthreadd. How do I even begin to track this thing down and shut it off?

Comment: @jerome: turn off your computer.  seriously -- kernel threads are part of the OS kernel, so that's the easiest way to get rid of them.  since it's linux, you can look into reconfiguring and/or recompiling the kernel, but that's probably overkill.  more likely, the trouble you're having is from some other program triggering kernel events, and you'll need to track that down some other way.